# How do I reference an existing VPC from AWS CDK code when declaring Lambda in VPC without the need to access internet during the `synth` step?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, amazon-vpc

In my work, I use cloudformation templates to manage AWS resources. Currently, we handcraft them, which has many problems (copy-paste as a main way to introduce new resources, human errors, no way to determine if your code is related to your cloudformation template). I want to automate cfn template generation by moving to CDK and generating templates with `synth` step (please note, I'm not moving to CDK as resource management, I'm just using it to generate templates).
When spiking this story, I ran into a problem that all our lambdas residing in vpc require a VPC object reference in lambda declaration. I'want to use existing VPC, but in cloudformation template we do not have to reference a vpc, we just define security groups and vpc subnets, and it's something that is done different in CDK.
My problem is that I would like to run `synth` step on developer machine, which might not have access to existing vpc (we use same template files for different environments), so I can not use `VPC.fromLookup()` - it does the online lookup, which I do not want to have.

Is it possible in CDK to define a Lambda in an existing VPC without having to access AWS endpoints during the `synth` step? Or am I missing the point of CDK and it's so by design?

Answer (score 3):

For lookup methods, the looked up values will be saved in `cdk.context.json` and you would commit that into git, making further online lookups unnecessary.

Refer to the [documentation on CDK context](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/context.html) for more information.

You can also do [`fromVpcAttributes`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.Vpc.html#static-fromwbrvpcwbrattributesscope-id-attrs) instead, which does not require any API calls at all, but requires you to provide all the information by hand.